# Using react-router with HTML arriving from server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In order to force react-router to treat links we should insert link as component: `<Link to="/path">` rather then `<a href="/path">`.
What should I do in situation when html content arrives from server and inserted via (oh no...) 
 `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

```
render() {            
        return (
            <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: store.posts[0].post_content}}
            />
        );
    }
```

What is the best way to force react-router to treat (internal) links in this html? Should I parse the html and convert it to components?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the best bet that I know of is to parse the HTML and replace the tags and swap the `href` attribute to `to` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of normal links

you could use a link that run a function like this:

```
<a OnClick={()=> history.push('route')}>go to</a>
```

sorry I haven't tested it :D